# Using custom functions in UPDATE with Propel 1.6

Tags: propel

I wonder how to add a function into the "SET" block of an SQL UPDATE with Propel 1.6.
E.g. 
    UPDATE foo SET myfield = length(:param) WHERE x = 3;

Such functions can be embedded into "->where()" but apparently not into "->update()".
What I'm looking for would be a syntax similar to this:

```
FooQuery::create()
        ->filterByX(3)
        ->update(array("MyField" => array("length(?)", 42));
```

Can I do this somehow or do I have to write my query as "custom SQL"?

Answer (score 0):

The update array is a series of column names and values.  The values are quoted values and hence whatever you put in there will be treated as a string (rather than a function).

Sorry, I can't see any other solution for you.